# getElementsByTagName() is not working with special characters for DOMDOCUMENT60

Tags: c++, xml, msxml, xmldom

i am trying to get a particular book id from xml file attached here(data.xml).
this is working fine ---- `getElementsByTagName(_bstr_t("book"))`
but when i search for a particular book id then 
it is throughing exception--- `getElementsByTagName(_bstr_t("book[@id='bk101']"))`

**this issue is seen in DOMDOCUMENT60**.

i don't know why it is not working with special characters.
does anyone face this issue before or have a suggestion?

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include<iostream>
#include "Msxml.h"
#import "msxml6.dll"
using namespace MSXML2;
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void LoadXML()
{
    HRESULT hr1, hr;
    hr1 = CoInitialize(NULL); //without this, cocreateinstance returns null pointer.

    _variant_t vaNodeVal("C://data.xml");

    VARIANT var1 = vaNodeVal;
    CComPtr<IXMLDOMDocument2> sSourceInputXml = 0;
    hr = sSourceInputXml.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML2::DOMDocument60));
    int ii=10;
    if (hr == S_OK && sSourceInputXml != NULL)
    {
        hr = sSourceInputXml->load(var1);
        int err = GetLastError();
        ii=20;
        try
        {
            ii = 30;

            CComQIPtr<MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodeList> xmlACPInput;
            std::cout << "\nworking";
            xmlACPInput = sSourceInputXml->getElementsByTagName(_bstr_t("book[@id='bk101']")); //throwing exception 
            std::cout << "\n not working";
            long lCount = 0;
            xmlACPInput->get_length(&lCount);
            bool isACP = false;
            if (lCount == 0)
            {
                isACP = false;
            }
            else
            {
                isACP = true;
            }
        }
        catch (exception ex)
        {
            ii = 1101;

        }
        catch (...)
        {
            ii = 1100;


        }
    }


    CoUninitialize();  
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    LoadXML();
    return 0;
}


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
  <book id="bk101">
    <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
    <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
    <genre>Computer</genre>
    <price>44.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
    <description>
      An in-depth look at creating applications
      with XML.
    </description>
  </book>
  <book id="bk102">
    <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
    <title>Midnight Rain</title>
    <genre>Fantasy</genre>
    <price>5.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
    <description>
      A former architect battles corporate zombies,
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen
      of the world.
    </description>
  </book>
  <book id="bk103">
    <author>Corets, Eva</author>
    <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
    <genre>Fantasy</genre>
    <price>5.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
    <description>
      After the collapse of a nanotechnology
      society in England, the young survivors lay the
      foundation for a new society.
    </description>
  </book>
</catalog>
```

Comment: Are you sure that msxml does support the [@id=''] notation?

Comment: if i change the above code to domdocument30 then it will work fine but in domdocument60 this special characters are throwing exception.

Answer (score 3):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb985161.aspx

> Since the expression can use either the XPath 1.0 or XSL Patterns
>   syntax, there needs to be a way to specify the selection language
>   before using these APIs. To maintain backwards compatibility with
>   existing code, the default selection language is XSL Patterns. To
>   change the current selection language to XPath, call the new
>   setProperty method (see IXMLDOMDocument2) using the SelectionLanguage
>   property name and the value

DomDocument30's default selection language is `XSL Patterns` which is a non-standard Microsoft implementation precursor to `XPath 1.0`.
And it implicitly supports to use XSL Patterns with getElementsByTagName method.

Since DomDocument60 does not support `XSL Patterns`, its default selection language is `XPath` and its getElementsByTagName method strictly requires a name instead of a pattern or query. So you need to query with XPath by using [selectNodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754523%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.
In DomDocument60, the equivalent of old `getElementsByTagName("book[@id='bk101']")` is `selectNodes("//book[@id='bk101']")`

So give it a try:

```
xmlACPInput = sSourceInputXml->selectNodes(_bstr_t("//book[@id='bk101']"));
```

Comment: yes it is working thanks it is really a nice explanation.